# Hi! How to update to last PHP? i am using Virtualmin and contabo

Tags: php, virtualmin

How to update to last PHP? i am using Virtualmin and contabo vps m. thank you

to update to last version of PHP

Answer (score 0):

**Virtualmin** repos *do not* provide any PHP versions. The default PHP version depends on whatever your OS provides.

If you need additional versions of PHP installed, it's easily doable, as we have documented it pretty clearly on our [Virtualmin ⇾ Multiple PHP Versions](https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/multiplephp/) page.